# Pitfalls to symlinking python2.7 to python?

Tags: python, path

I have a CentOS 6.7 machine with the "system" python (2.6.6) installed from an RPM at `/usr/bin/python`.  We installed an additional version installed from source (2.7.11) used for development purposes installed in `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.

Is there any harm to creating a symlink at `/usr/local/bin/python` pointing at  `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`?  My impression is "no", because any programs that want to use the system python will have their path set correctly to do so, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have programs that do not hard-code `/usr/bin/python` but e.g. use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

than this can get you into trouble if `/usr/local/bin` preceeds `/usr/bin` in an environment.

My recommendation is that you should not install python in `/usr/local/bin` at all, but in something like `/opt/python/2.7.11`. Any programs that need that python should go into a virtualenv of their own using:

```
virtualenv -p /opt/python/2.7.11/bin/python /path/for/2_7_utility
```

that way none of those utilities will have version dependency problems between each other, and nothing will bite the older system python.

If someone wants `python` to resolve to `/opt/python/2.7.11/bin/python` they should just add an alias to do so.

Comment: My recollection is that an alias isn't the right way to go if you're using virtualenv for python because when you enter the virtual environment, the alias will trump the command path, and the virtualenv wants you to use its copy of python.

Comment: I was able to work around the issue mentioned in my previous comment by unaliasing in `postactivate` and redoing the alias in `postdeactivate`.